# What entity to use for committees (both a group and a collection of projects)?

Tags: groups, civivolunteer

Having some trouble mapping CiviCRM database entities to conceptual entities in my organization. We have long lists of committees; each committee can have any number of projects; projects can have any number of volunteer opportunities. Working backwards from CiviVolunteer, that seems like I should have Projects and Campaigns to group them. But Committees more naturally map to Groups. So is it a question of using both and keeping them synced and somehow associated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a sub-contact type of an Organization called 'Committee'. The committee can be set to the 'Owner' of each volunteer project. It might be useful to useful to have a campaign for each committee as well.

Also, by adding it as a sub-contact type you can add the individual relationships against the committee and track their start and end dates.

Comment: Sounds perfect, many thanks.